# autoload another method if method is undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, autoload

Can i fallback to another method if method of a given object is not found?

say i've got (just to get the idea)

```
var phoneCall new function() {

  function toMom() {

  }

  function catchAll() {

  }

 }

q = new phoneCall;
q.toMom();

q.toDad() //should fire phoneCall.catchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

No - not in a cross-browser way.  Firefox and a couple other engines have an approach to do this, but it won't work in Chrome, IE, etc.  Proxies will eventually allow some functionality like this, but that's still in the early phase of engine adoption.

---

Edit: here's some code that might get you started with something that will work though:

```
var phoneCall = {
    to: function(whom) {
        (phoneCall.people[whom] || phoneCall.catchAll)();
    },
    people: {
        mom: function() {
            // call mom functionality
        }
    },
    catchAll: function() {
        // generic call functionality
    }
};


phoneCall.to('mom');
phoneCall.to('dad'); // invokes catchAll
```

Comment: thanks, but this is equal actually to making a function with a switch in it and a default case, not the mapping i wanted. :) thanks anyway

Comment: Ya,I figured this isn't exactly what you were going for. The real answer to the question was the "No" part... the remainder was just a potential work around :). In JavaScript, the closest you will get is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/NoSuchMethod, but as stated above, that works in FF only.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
q.toDad() || q.catchAll();
```

EDIT:

User jmar77 is right about this code being invalid, since it is returning a function's result rather than the function itself... My bad. Here's the updated code:

```
function phoneCall() {
   this.toMom = function() {
        console.log('Mom was called.');
    }
   this.catchAll = function() {
        console.log('Catch all was called');
    }
}

q = new phoneCall();
q.toMom();
q.toDad ? q.toDad() : q.catchAll();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/yzDh7/

Comment: That will throw an error. You could, however, do something like `q.toDad ? q.toDad() : q.catchAll()`. But I don't think that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks jmar77, you are right. The way I understand what the OP wants to do, I think it's the only way to go. I still think it's a valid solution, don't you?

Comment: I think it's a possible solution, but it puts the burden of checking on the code consuming `phoneCall`, rather than internalizing that logic. I made a stab at something close to what he described, but I think what he really wants is something like, e.g., Ruby's missing_method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a getter pattern:

http://jsfiddle.net/XjgPW/1/

```
var myObject = (function() {
    var methods = {
        method1: function () {
            console.log('method1 called');
        },
        method2: function () {
            console.log('method2 called');
        },  
        defaultMethod: function () {
            console.log('defaultMethod called');
        }
    };

    var get = function (name) {
        if (methods.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            return methods[name];
        } else {
            return methods.defaultMethod;
        }
    };

    return {
        get: get
    };
}());
```

Comment: Hey there thanks for your approach, but actually you can accomplish same stuff with a function with a switch in it and a default case, the important is the way you call it.. myObject.get('method2')(); what i would like is myobject.someMethodMissing() maps to myobject.catchAll(); thanks for your time anyway, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates calling a fallback method if the first method doesn't exist:

```
q = {};
q.toDad = function() {
    console.log("to dad");
}
(q.toMom || q.toDad)();  // Will output "to dad" to the console

q.toMom = function() {
    console.log("to mom");
}
(q.toMom || q.toDad)();  // Will output "to mom" to the console
```